# Questions about large-scale multiple testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

1. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons#Large-scale_multiple_testing)

   > Traditional methods for multiple comparisons adjustments focus on
   >   correcting for modest numbers of comparisons, often in an analysis of
   >   variance. A different set of techniques have been developed for
   >   "large-scale multiple testing", in which thousands or even greater
   >   numbers of tests are performed.  ... Particularly in the field of
   >   genetic association studies, **there has been a serious problem with
   >   non-replication** — a result being strongly statistically significant
   >   in one study but failing to be replicated in a follow-up study. Such
   >   non-replication can have many causes, but it is widely considered that
   >   failure to fully account for the consequences of making multiple
   >   comparisons is one of the causes.

   I was wondering what the problem with non-replication is, and why it
   can be because of the failure to fully account for the consequences
   of making multiple comparisons?
2. > **For large-scale testing problems where the goal is to provide definitive results**, the familywise error rate remains the most
   >   accepted parameter for ascribing significance levels to statistical
   >   tests.
   >
   > Alternatively, **if a study is viewed as exploratory, or if
   >   significant results can be easily re-tested in an independent study**,
   >   control of the false discovery rate (FDR) is often
   >   preferred.

   What does "the goal is to provide definitive results" mean, and why
   is FWER most accepted in such cases?

   What does "if a study is viewed as exploratory, or if significant results can be easily re-tested in an independent study" mean, and why is FDR preferred in such cases?
3. > The FDR, defined as the expected proportion of false positives among
   >   all significant tests, allows researchers to identify a set of
   >   "candidate positives", of which a high proportion are likely to be
   >   true. The false positives within the candidate set can then be
   >   identified in a follow-up study.

   Since FDR "allows researchers to identify a set of 'candidate
   positives'", which I understand as the estimate of false positive
   individual nulls, why do we need further that "the false positives
   within the candidate set can then be identified in a follow-up
   study"?

   Am I right that FWER also can "allow researchers to identify a set
   of 'candidate positives'", as the set of individual tests that
   rejects their nulls.

Thanks and regards!